# how to set 2 pictures side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm trying to put 2 pictures side by side. i thought i can do that by using bootstrap grid but it doesn't work for me. [my code](https://codepen.io/soroosh96/pen/GOzzeX)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aHxLM6563JbtHMwdbWTAEzIbILKwxsuM-s6SIGR2zki8h5wmSf-Semz8xhNIbwbHGwAW3CE3j-g=w640-h400-e365" alt="google">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.hisocial.com/eng/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fb_login_1.png" alt="facebook">
```

I want the portfolio pictures to be like this:

[his code](https://codepen.io/soroosh96/pen/dZarEL)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** added "text-right" so the left image is properly positioned

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aHxLM6563JbtHMwdbWTAEzIbILKwxsuM-s6SIGR2zki8h5wmSf-Semz8xhNIbwbHGwAW3CE3j-g=w640-h400-e365" alt="google">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.hisocial.com/eng/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fb_login_1.png" alt="facebook">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make your that you've included the bootstrap framework before using classes such as "row" and "col-xs-6". Include this line of code in the  if you haven't -

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Use col-md-* for desktops & laptops instead of xs. XS is for small devices. Try this code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aHxLM6563JbtHMwdbWTAEzIbILKwxsuM-s6SIGR2zki8h5wmSf-Semz8xhNIbwbHGwAW3CE3j-g=w640-h400-e365" alt="google">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="http://www.hisocial.com/eng/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fb_login_1.png" alt="facebook">
</div>
```